# up-to-date phpmyadmin repository for Ubuntu

Tags: phpmyadmin

The default Repo on my server only seems to cater for the installation of phpMyAdmin `4.5.4.1`.

In the hopes to get something more up-to-date, I added the below Repo:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nijel/phpmyadmin`

But this only gets me to `4.6.6`.

Is there another Repo that will get me anything close to `4.8.5`?

*(I know I can obtain directly via wget If I wanted)*